# iOS status bar background overlaps UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

The main view of my app is a scrollable `UICollectionView` embedded in a `UITabBarController`. I'm not using a navigation bar and when the user scrolls he sees the cells behind the status bar, because the status bar has no background.

[image: Cells behind status bar]

I've used `UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .white` in my AppDelegate to apply a background and to make the status bar look like desired.

This works fine, but doesn't look nice when you're presenting a `UIAlertController`.

[image: UIAlertController and status bar background]

The white status bar stays above the dimmed background.

Is there a better way to apply a background to the status bar or a way to keep it behind the `UIAlertController` background?

Comment: Where did you get the `statusBarView`? Is that your custom view? For the sake of people who will attempt to show a sample solution, do you use storyboards or do you code the constraints?

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .white` happens in the AppDelegate. No storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a `UIView` with a background color at the top of your presenting `UIView`.

Height of status bar can come from `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame`. And update your view size when receiving `UIApplication.didChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`.

Comment: Works very well. The only thing that bothers me is that `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height` isn't up-to-date when didChangeStatusBarFrame fires. I guess it's because some layout needs to happen first. I'm now wrapping the update in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` to get the correct height. Not the best, but it works. Let me know if you have a better idea.

Comment: No information about new frame in the info dictionary of the notification?